Dnd-kit transition doesn't work on drop of draggable item
I'm creating a simple quiz which has 4 droppable areas and 4 draggable items and idea behind this quiz to move all items into correct order or just to correct droppable zone.

Now everything is working - items are swiping (when I move f.e. item 1 to droppable 3 then droppable 1 has item 3 and droppable 3 has item 1)

The problem is draggables don't have any transition on drag end. I've implemented transition in following way:
draggable/index.tsx:
import { useDraggable } from '@dnd-kit/core';
import { CSS } from '@dnd-kit/utilities';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';

import s from './draggable.module.scss';

type TProps = {
   children: ReactNode;
   id: string;
};

export const Draggable = ({ id, children }: TProps) => {
   const { attributes, listeners, setNodeRef, transform, isDragging } = useDraggable({
      id,
   });
   const style = {
      ...{ transition: 'transform 250ms ease' },
      ...(transform ? { transform: CSS.Translate.toString(transform) } : {}),
      ...(isDragging ? { transition: 'none' } : {}),
   };

   return (
      <button
         ref={setNodeRef}
         className={clsx(s.wrapper, isDragging && s.dragging)}
         style={style}
         {...listeners}
         {...attributes}
      >
         {children}
      </button>
   );
};

LINKS
CODE
github: /src/app/page.tsx
github: /src/components/dnd/draggable/index.tsx
github: /src/components/dnd/droppable/index.tsx
DEPLOYED EXAMPLE
vercel: Try it yourself

use a state and useEffect to track drag ending.
const { attributes, listeners, setNodeRef, transform, isDragging, active } 
= useDraggable({id});

const [style, setStyle] = useState({});


useEffect(() => {

  if (!isDragging && active) {

     setStyle((prevStyle) => ({

        ...prevStyle,

        transition: 'transform 250ms ease',

        transform: CSS.Translate.toString(transform),

     }));

  }

  if (!active) {

     setStyle({

        transition: 'transform 250ms ease',

     });

  }

}, [isDragging, transform, active]);

when the current drag has just ended, active is true  and isDragging is false so the transition is applied to the transform style.
on the hand When active is false the transition resets.

Unfortunately with your approach transition disappeared completely
